# set missing value with proc format

Tags: sas, proc-format

I'm quite new to SAS and I use the `proc format` to attribute value to codes :

```
proc format;
    value code_to_value
        -1 = .
        1 = 0.5
        2 = 0.25
        3 - high = 0;
run;
```

I then convert it to a numeric column in my dataset.

```
DATA foo; 
    SET bar;
    my_var = put(my_var ,code_to_value.);
RUN;
```

The problem is that this code set all `-1` code to `.`, but as a character, not as a missing value.

How can I set it to missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `put()` function creates a character value.  Combine with `input()` if you want to convert back to numeric, eg:

```
DATA foo; 
  SET bar;
  my_var = input(put(my_var ,code_to_value.),best.);
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

Allan's `input(put` is a very common and legitimate construct.

Here is more information for a deeper understanding.

The `value` statement of `Proc FORMAT` creates a `format`.  Formats *always* performs a 'to-text' mapping.

- A numeric format maps a numeric value to a character value
- A character format maps a character value to a character value
- formats can be applied programmatically using the `PUT`, `PUTC` and `PUTN` functions

A `invalue` statement creates an `informat`.

- A numeric informat maps a character value to a numeric value
- A character informat maps a character value to a character value
- informats can be applied programmatically using the `INPUT`, `INPUTC` and `INPUTN` functions

There is no format/function combination that directly maps a numeric value to a numeric value.

Using `INPUT()` with a numeric will perform an implicit conversion to character (not a bad thing per se) prior to using the specified numeric informat.  This example shows `INVALUE` and `INPUT`.

```
proc format;
    invalue code_to_value
        -1 = .
        1 = 0.5
        2 = 0.25
        3 - high = 0;
run;

data have;
  do my_var = -2 to 4; output; end;
run;

DATA want; 
    SET have;
    my_varx = input(my_var, code_to_value.);
RUN;
----- LOG -----
NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values at the places given by:
```